# Go Fish Card Game Error in Function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, typeerror

Okay so, here's a bit of background information:

There are 4 players in my card game, each player has a hand.
pHands is a list of the 4 other players' hands
(there are 4 other lists within pHands)

Lists look something like this in pHands (the players' hands):
[ 'as', '2s', '4h', ............. , 'ad']

The first character of each element in the list is the card, and the second character of each element in the list is the suite.

I want to take out the suit in every element of the list, so I have the following functions:

```
def slicing(player):

    slicing_p1(player)
    slicing_p2(player)

def slicing_p1(player):

    pHandsSlice = pHands[player]
    pHandsString = ", ".join(pHands[player])
    x = len(pHands[player])
    for i in range(x):
        y = ''.join(pHandsSlice[i])
        y = y.replace(y[1], "")
        global myStrList
        global myStr
        myStrList = myStrList + y
        myStr = myStr + y + ","

def slicing_p2(player):

    x = len(myStr)
    global myStr
    global myStrList
    myStr = myStr[:-1]
    myStrList = list(myStrList)
```

then I execute these functions:

```
slicing(0)
slicing(1) <------- this is where the error occurs.
```

ERROR:

```
 File "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\UPDATE Assignment 2 (of 2)\GoFishPack\GoFishGameEngineSkeleton.py", line 63, in slicing
slicing_p1(player)
 File "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\UPDATE Assignment 2 (of 2)\GoFishPack\GoFishGameEngineSkeleton.py", line 75, in slicing_p1
myStrList = myStrList + y
```

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

What's going on here and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is get the suit of every card, then just do something like this:

```
for playerhand in pHands:
    for card in playerhand:
        print card[1]
```

If you want to get the suits of all the cards in a particular player's hand, then do something like:

```
def suits(player):
    for card in pHands[player]:
        print card[1]
```

You can then do `suits(1)`, for example, to print the suit of every card in player 1's hand.

If you want to **remove** the suits from every card (i.e., so each player is left with just a list of numbers), then:

```
def remove_suits():
    newhands = [] # temporary variable that will replace pHands
    for playerhand in pHands: # for each hand
        newhand = [] # temporary variable for what their new hand will be
        for card in playerhand:
            newcard = card[0] # make the card equal to only the first character in the hand, in this case, the number
            newhand.append(newcard) # store this card to the temporary variable
        newhands.append(newhand) # push this hand to the temporary variable for the new set of hands
    global pHands # if you're working with globals
    pHands = newhands # now change pHands to be equal to your new list
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using remove_suits and modified my code a bit and it's working now. I'm just trying to figure out why the append isn't working out of curiosity...

Comment: @Gaze If this method worked for you, check the checkbox to the left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do something like  + , python expects that  is a list. Here is an example of that.

```
>>> [1, 2, 30] + [1, 3]
[1, 2, 30, 1, 3]
```

This process is called concatenation. Since you can only concatenate two lists, you receive the error you did when you try to concatenate a list with something that is not a list. `y` in your case is a str. What you are trying to do is append `y` to your list, `myStrList`. You do that by calling the "append" method on `myStrList`.

```
>>> myStrList = [1, 2, 4]
>>> y = 'a'
>>> myStrList.append(y)
[1, 2, 4, 'a']
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

I get this error when I use myStrList.append(y) ...

Answer (score 0):

its because you are trying to concatenate a list and a str

say you the player hand list is `['as','2s','4d','4h']` that means the for loop will ouput

```
a
2
4
4
```

and if you do `type(y)` it comes out as `<type "str">` so they are strings

then you try to add the strings too a list on this line:

```
myStrList = myStrList + y
```

you need to use `append()` to make a string into a new item of the list

so on each iteration of th for loop you need to do:

```
myStrList.append(y)
```

Comment: It's telling me str object has no attribute append. What's happening here?

Comment: that means that `myStrList` is a string instead of a list but thats weird becuase before it said it was a list maybe you should post youre full code